# X Axis sculpting is diagonal

Tags: sculpting, mirror, axis

[image]

I can’t get my x axis mirroring while sculpting to be straight. it keeps mirroring on the diagonal and i can’t find the issue. I’m new to Blender but over tried resetting location, rotation, etc that’s recommended in the threads I could find.

Comment: hello could you please show a screenshot?

Comment: @moonboots I added one! let me know if there's anything else you'd need to see

Comment: Are you sure that you have applied the rotation? Please share your file